# Why aren't UIViewAnimationsOptions available in the drop down menu?

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I'm working through the Code With Chris card matching game and when setting up the animation, he presses "." to bring up a list of options to select from. When I do the same thing my list of things to select from is different. I tried putting in the text manually but Xcode doesn't recognize it. What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the tutorial is calling `UIView.animate` but you are calling `UIView.animateKeyFrames`. Those are different methods and take a different set of options.

(There have also been some changes in the code completion interface since that tutorial was created.)

Comment: Thanks I'll look at my initial code again.

Comment: I tried again but this time after pressing "." I typed out "CurveEaseOut" and I was able to select it.